# Easiest way to add a second flat rate shipping method on Magento 2?

Tags: shipping-methods, delivery

```
Magento 2.4.5-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
```

I need 2 simple flat rate delivery methods - something like:

- local Atlanta delivery (for all delivery for anywhere in Atlanta) = $10
- Nationwide shipping (for anything outside of Atlanta) = $20

This doesn't need to be fancy at all (no address verification or anything like that) - just let the customer click it (make the selection).

I know there are ways to add this programmatically but that seems unnecessarily complicated.

**Is there an easy way to add the 2nd Flat Delivery/Shipping method via Table Rates or any other simple method?**

Answer (score 1):

Please use this extension to create multiple flat rates shipping methods.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-multi-flat-rates-shipping/

Comment: I've tried to install it by running the following command in my Magento root directory (composer require mageplaza/module-multi-flat-rates) and I get this Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'RewriterInterface' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in /home/florist/public_html/vendor/laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin/src/DependencyRewriterPluginDelegator.php on line 27